# Can i change AutoStyles colors for undefined variables?

Tags: color, variable

I want to change from blue to red the color of the undefined variables; but only for the current Notebook

Comment: Gonzalo, Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Please (1) Read the [faqs](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) (2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {AutoStyleOptions, "UndefinedSymbolStyle"}]
(* {FontColor -> RGBColor[0., 0.173, 0.765]} *)
```

to any color of your choice, say `Red`, evaluating

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {AutoStyleOptions, "UndefinedSymbolStyle"}] = 
   {FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 0., 0.]}
```

anywhere in the notebook.

Before evaluation of the above code:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this via the Format-> Option Inspector,  Choosing your context  (Selection, sheet or Global) and looking for UndefinedSymbolStyle in the lookup box.

[image]

Comment: :o, i will check that; i'm making notebook creator (create notebook with style)